# BitBucket 1.0 REST API retrieve when reviewers were added to a PR

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is there a way to get the timestamp of when a reviewer was added to a PR? I'm currently using `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests` to get the list of reviewers and if they've approved or not.